# MongoDB backup in Secondary node in full backup

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

We are using MongoDB Community Edition (6.0.1) (PSA) and planning to take a backup while the database is running on a live secondary node(full cluster level backup). Is it possible to do so without impacting production? Can someone please provide guidance and a backup plan for the secondary node? Thank you.

Comment: Does the [MongoDB Backup Methods page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/backups/) from the vendor answer your questions?